# Are there any models that can handle out of sample features?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, missing-data, robust

So I'm facing a regression problem where I have a categorical features (factor) where the levels are very commonly different between the training set and the test set.

I have multiple measurements per subject, where the context where the measurement was made changes constantly and is represented by the `current_context` variable. I would like to measure how the context affects the measurement on a per subject basis, and try to predict new values for the response, given the context and other, fixed, predictors.

Example:

```
Training:

subject_id current_context response
1 C15 55
1 D46 44
1 A416 99
...
10^6 G426 44
10^6 G426 44

Test:
subject_id current_context response
1 C15 65
1 D55 55
1 E416 101
...
10^6 G426 44
10^6 E417 65
```

One solution for this would be that I could create different models (kind of like [backoff](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~jason/465/PDFSlides/lect05-smoothing.pdf) in NLP) and fall back to simpler models until all the features are available. In the example I would have one model trained on all the features, and two more trained only on one feature at a time.
But that's an engineering overhead I would like to avoid.

Another solution as suggested is to use hierarchical modeling. This is probably impossible in my case, as I would like to have the `subject_id` as a random effect, which could be in the millions and that doesn't scale AFAIK. Another problem I've noticed when trying that is that because the `current_context` can also have hundreds of thousands of values, it leads to computational issues as well (I get the error that linpack cannot create a matrix of adequate size)

So I was wondering if there are (regression) models that have this kind of robustness built in, i.e. are able to produce estimates for the dependent even if some of the features used during training are missing, or if new levels appear in factor.

Comment: Your edits are helpful (presuming they more closely resemble your real problem) but you're still missing [a lot of details](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl).

Comment: See this similar post:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298137/dealing-with-new-factor-levels-in-a-regression-in-r/384749#384749

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your exact situation, it could be helpful to use a mixed model and treat each country as a random effect (specifically, a random intercept) rather than a fixed effect. This gives your model a way to estimate the effect of a country that appears nowhere in its training data.

Another approach would be to replace the single categorical variable "country" with a few different variables that measure characteristics of the country such as its population density or Human Development Index. Then, when the model has to handle a new country, it doesn't actually have to handle a new level of a categorical feature.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I've considered mixed models, but they wouldn't work in my case because of the size of the data and the number of levels (one per subject which could be in the millions)

Comment: Millions of subjects, maybe, but you can't have millions of countries, since there's less than 200 countries in the world. I'm suggesting a per-country random intercept.

Comment: The example I gave is a toy one, I'll adjust the question to make it closer to my actual problem.

Comment: If you want good answers, you need to give full details instead of a fake version with what you think the important parts are. [Here is a guide.](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl)