# How to predict from a model when newly occurring levels appear in a factor variable?

Tags: predictive-models, feature-selection, random-forest

I have a randomForest model that performs well on my training and testing data (results of the previous fiscal year). However, I need to predict on different, more recent, data from this fiscal year.

In the new data that I need to predict from, one of the factor variables has new levels that didn't exist in the original training data.

What's the best way to handle these new levels? I don't have any training data which includes the new levels, or rather, I don't yet have a response variable for any of the cases which include the levels, so I can't retrain the model to include the new levels, but the variable in question was a significant part of the previous model--retraining the model without it would more than likely reduce my accuracy.

Another option would be to impute an existing value onto the current data, replacing the values that aren't in the model with ones that are. This feels janky to me, but without any response data, it's hard to know how much I'm affecting my predictions.

I'm less interested in identifying types of models that will solve the problem in future and more interested in finding a successful way forward for this particular situation (although, I suppose building a new model is a viable option), ie. "What should I do now?" as opposed to "Next time I see this problem coming, what can do to head it off?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any models that can handle out of sample features?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224777/are-there-any-models-that-can-handle-out-of-sample-features)

Comment: I would look at augmentation.  This is one of the weaknesses of universal learners: they can only learn what they have been trained.  The old model doesn't have much inkling of the new category.  I would wrap the updated data, and the predictor as inputs for a logistic regressor for whether or not a new sample belongs to the new level.  If the logistic regressor does a fair job, then use it.

Comment: Just as a follow-up--this time around, I imputed some existing factor levels for those observations that had new levels based on similar levels. I'd still be curious what the best move for the future is, when I've accidentlaly backed myself into a similar corner.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298137/dealing-with-new-factor-levels-in-a-regression-in-r/384749#384749